# PHP: Align text in text file which is generated by php script

Tags: php

I am creating a text file using php script in which text will be from a **textarea**, now I am able to write text in that text file but it is **left aligned** but I want to align it in center or after a given (particular) space.
I am using following php code to write that **textarea's** text/value.

```
 echo str_pad($headerText,100," ",STR_PAD_LEFT).PHP_EOL;
```

User input could be as below:

[image]

and output file is as below :

[image]

here first line seems fine but in next lines text is not after given spage(100).

Comment: What's the content of `$headerText`?

Comment: content will be string or a paragraph entered in text area, as it could be a complete address in different lines

Comment: @mario.klump I have attached sample images, please check.

Comment: It is working on my local machine. Could you please also add your full `PHP` code and the part of your `HTML` form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use STR_PAD_BOTH to "center" the text. See http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-pad.php section pad_type / example #1 for more information.

If you have more then one line of text my approach would be to split the string into one string per line (and have them stored into an array). Afterwards I'll apply str_pad and then merge the strings adding newline-commands.

```
$headerText="Hello\nWorld!\nHello World!";
echo $headerText;

echo "\n\n";     // Just for a nicer output

$strArr = explode("\n",$headerText);     // Split
$final="";

for($i=0;$i<count($strArr);$i++)
{
     $final.=str_pad($strArr[$i],50,"_",STR_PAD_BOTH)."\n";    // "center" and concat
}
echo $final;
```

Answer (score 0):

use STR_PAD_BOTH to for text to be center.

Comment: in this case also it is working only for first line of **textarea**. please check my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

```
<?php
 $myFile = "myfile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
fprintf ($fh, "\r\n%1s %14s %14s",  "saa", "sasasasa","sasasas");
fclose($fh);
?>
```